# Is reading a pointer to deleted memory undefined behavior?

Tags: c++

Consider

```
Foo* f = new Foo();
delete f;
Foo* g = f;
```

Is the final statement now undefined due to my reading a pointer to memory that I don't own? To me it violates the one-past-the-end rule, so it ought to be.

Note that

```
Foo* f;
Foo* g = f;
```

is undefined.

Comment: Apologies for the format. I'm on a phone. Will try to fix.

Comment: @P45Imminent _"To me it violates the one-past-the-end rule, so it ought to be."_ Can you elaborate/cite about that rule please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is the final statement now undefined due to my reading a pointer to memory that I don't own?

No, the statement

```
Foo* g = f;
```

will not call *undefined behavior* per se. The copy operation for a pointer value can be done safely at any time.

But further using the pointer `f` or `g` for dereferencing will cause *undefined behavior* after `f` was deleted.

You can even use these pointer values safely for e.g. logging purposes:

```
std::cout << "g = " << g << std::endl;
```

---

> Note that
>
> ```
> Foo* f;
> Foo* g = f;
> ```
>
> is undefined.

That assumption is wrong. It's neither *undefined behavior*, again it's dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is *undefined behavior*, plain assignment is not.

Comment: Actually from **[basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation]**: *Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior. Any other use of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior.*

Comment: It's hard to say what is 'defined' or 'undefined' in the second case. In which way it is defined? That `g` is going to be equal to *something*?

Comment: @SergeyA As mentioned, the plain assignment statement won't call _UB_, regardless it the original value was initialized correctly or not.

Comment: @NathanOliver The OP might be too unclear about the context here, as mentioned _the plain assignment won't call UB_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am just saying you should call it what it is.  It is not standard defined behavior but rather implementation defined.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, like I said, it's hard to say from practical purpose in which way it is defined. Defined assumes you can say what the program will do, or what it's state going to be. In this case, you can't say what the program will do or what it's state is going to be.

Comment: @SergeyA The question is (as far I've understood it right), if the `Foo* g = f;` is undefined, and it's not.

Answer (score 3):

You can copy the pointer, there's nothing preventing you from doing that, but the pointer is to de-allocated memory so it shouldn't be used. If you do use it, you walk right into *undefined behaviour*, so it's really not a good idea.

Since the `f` pointer itself is still on the stack, you can copy it without concern. It's just a strange thing to do.

Comment: And kind of useless anyhow: You are not allowed to dereference it, so why would you want a copy? A pointer to deleted memory is worse than yesterday's newspaper.....

Comment: Maybe people like to hoard their old pointers like they do newspapers.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not useful code, but if you think of it as after the delete, `f` contains a stale pointer.  You example copies that stale pointer to `g`.  You are not doing anything really bad until you try to access something with `g` via the stale pointer.